# How do I hide guides in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools, cc-2014

I am working with Photoshop and I was wondering if you can hide the guides temporally just like in Pixelmator?

Comment: Welcome to GD.  Please take a minute and review our help center at the top right to assist you in asking a question.  We always try to welcome new users but we also expect users to have a basic understanding of how some software works, professionalism and show effort in a question.  At this time your question is very basic and that is the reason why you're receiving downvotes from the community.

Answer (score 32):

On a Mac, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>
On Windows, I think it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>

Comment: In Photoshop CC 2019, the menu item you missed is pretty well hidden; I missed it the first time, too. Pull down the View menu. About halfway down there is a Show Menu. Scroll down to that menu item and a submenu will pop up. Select or deselect the Guides menu item. As Vincent mentioned, the shortcut is Cmd/Ctrl ;, but I never remember something that obscure unless I use it a lot. Knowing where the menu item is hidden may help.

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in Windows or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in Mac

Take your time and click through the menus, its not that difficult to find things like this without asking us. Could even google search but that's probably longer (and less productive) than taking 10 minutes to familiarize yourself with the menus.

Comment: I think 90 thousand views in 2018 proofs you wrong. You might reconsider how you answer. "It's not that difficult without asking us" shows some attitude you maybe want to get rid off.